# $p$-value for non-standard asymptotics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, asymptotics

Suppose I have an asymptotic result like

$$\sqrt{n}(T_n - \theta) \overset{D}{\to} \sum_{i=1}^k \lambda_i X_i$$

where $X_i$ are independent $\chi^2_1$. i.e. some test statistics $T_n$ is asymptotically the linear combination of weighted $\chi_1^2$ variables. Can I get $p$-values from such a result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you know the $\lambda_i$, simulation is feasible.

Consider

```
library(MASS)
k <- 3
lambda <- c(.2,.3,.4) # pick your lambdas here

reps <- 100000
distr <- rep(NA,reps)
for (i in 1:reps){
     distr[i] <- sum(lambda*rchisq(k,1))
}
distr <- sort(distr)

teststat <- 2 # pick your teststat here
pvalue <- which.min(abs(teststat-distr))/reps # assuming a left-tailed test
```

So effectively, we "plug" the test statistic `teststat` into the empirical cdf, i.e., find the proportion of realizations from the simulation that (which, for `reps` large, precisely estimates the probability that) a random variable from the null distribution takes a value less (we consider a left-tailed test here, with obvious modifications to other alternatives) than the test statistic - i.e., the $p$-value:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There are two useful approximations and at least three computations that would be exact with infinite precision arithmetic.

Let's call the distribution $Q(\lambda)$. And write $\bar\lambda$ for the mean of $\lambda$ and $\tau$ for the mean of $\lambda^2$.

The two approximations are implemented in `pchisqsum` in the R `survey` package

The Satterthwaite approximation is overwhelmingly the most common way this distribution is evaluated in practice.  It approximates $Q(\lambda)$ by $a\chi^2_d$ where $a$ and $d$ are chosen to get the right mean and variance. Specifically, $a=\tau/\bar\lambda$, and $d=k\bar\lambda^2/\tau$.  Until you get far out in the right tail, the Satterthwaite approximation is far more accurate than it has any right to be. Also, in the common scenario where the $\lambda$ are eigenvalues of a matrix, you don't need the eigendecomposition: you can compute the Satterthwaite approximation in $O(k^2)$ time for general matrices and faster for specially structured matrices.

The saddlepoint approximation is less accurate for modest tail probabilities, but much more accurate for small ones -- it has uniformly bounded relative error, and the error decreases as $k$ increases.  It's the only one that works for very small tail probabilities with ordinary double-precision arithmetic.

There are two fairly old computational methods that work well. These are both impemented in the `CompQuadForm` package for R.  They both get catastrophic rounding error as the right tail probability approaches machine epsilon and they slow down for large $k$.

- Farebrother's method represents the probability as an infinite series in Beta functions. It requires the $\lambda$s to be positive, and for large $k$ the biggest one can't be that much larger than the rest. You might think negative $\lambda$ isn't important, but it lets you do the same trick with $F$ distributions having the same denominator
- Davies's method takes advantage of the fact that you can just write down the characteristic function, which can then be inverted by numerical integration
- There's a third computational method, due to Bausch, that has very good error/effort bounds in extreme settings as long as you have arbitrary precision arithmetic. He invented it for a problem in string theory. It *really needs* multiple-precision arithmetic.

There are also some improvements on the Satterthwaite approximation

- matching more than two moments.  In my opinion these aren't terribly appealing: if you have all the $\lambda$s you might as well use Davies's or Farebrother's methods.  If $k$ is large and you  only have the matrix whose eigenvalues are the $\lambda$s,  these methods are no faster than a full eigendecomposition.
- leading-eigenvalue approximation. When $k$ is large,  approximate the sum as $\left(\sum_{i<m}\lambda_i Z_i\right)+a_m\chi^2_{d_m}$, where the last term is a Satterthwaite approximation with the $k-m$ smallest eigenvalues.

A student and I reviewed these in the large $k$ case; we have [a blog post](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2017/12/06/how-to-add-chi-squareds/) and a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2019.05.002).